# Searching and splitting database values with search terms and querying using Linq

Tags: c#, linq-to-entities

I'm trying to figure out how to perform a search that maps a word from my search term to a word that's stored in a cluster of words(paragraph) in the database.

This works pretty much ok, except that it also returns results with letters that are in the Contain and not an exact match which is ideally what i want. I have tried a few variations but ideally looking for someone to shed some light on this. Any help is greatly appreciated!

So if i passed in "the" it would return:

**the** house has...
Ano**the**r House (this should not return)

```
string[] seperator = { " " };
string[] filteredSearchTerms = searchTerm.Split(seperator, StringSplitOptions.None);

   var entities = new Entity();
   List<dto> dto = (from t in entities.tbl
                     where
                     filteredSearchTerms.Any(v => t.Description.Contains(v)) 
                     select new dto
                     {
                       description = t.Description
                     }).Take(10).ToList();
```

Regards,

Tez

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `Regex` like this:

```
string[] seperator = { " " };
string[] filteredSearchTerms = searchTerm.Split(seperator, StringSplitOptions.None);

   var entities = new Entity();
   List<dto> dto = (from t in entities.tbl
                     where
                     filteredSearchTerms.Any(v => System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch(t, string.Format(@"\b{0}\b", v))) 
                     select new dto
                     {
                       description = t.Description
                     }).Take(10).ToList();
```

this regular expression matches the whole word using the word delimiter `\b`. See [this](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) for more info.

**EDIT**

Since `Regex` is not supported by Linq to Entities, one way to achieve this is to first fetch your data using your original query then filter them on the client side using Linq to Objects like this:

```
List<dto> dto = (from t in entities.tbl
                 where
                 filteredSearchTerms.Any(v => t.Description.Contains(v)) 
                 select new dto
                 {
                   description = t.Description
                 }).AsEnumerable()
                   .Where(obj => filteredSearchTerms.Any(v => System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch(obj, string.Format(@"\b{0}\b", v))))
                   .Take(10).ToList();
```

Comment: Just looking into your answer, at the moment i'm getting an error. IsMatch not supported with linq to entity bool.

Comment: @TezWingfield look at these SO questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5720987/how-to-simulate-regular-expressions-in-linq-to-sql and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3493501/using-match-in-a-linq-statement

Comment: Works very well, Great work. The only concern is that using AsEnumerable places the collection into memory which you have already added one reference into memory via the initial query? Never the less great answer!

Comment: @TezWingfield in order to be able to use `Regex` the only way is to use Linq to objects, so you have to query against data in memory which is inefficient in the first place but this query runs in two stages, first get a subset of data containing the terms then narrow it down using regular expression. If the first stage's data isn't that much big, this solution works fine and you don't need to worry about its performance.

Answer (score 0):

If you want whole words, you can always include spaces on either side of your search term like this:

```
var filteredSearchTerms = searchTerm.Split(' ').Select(x => " " + x + " ");
```

I did not push this to an array since the extension method `Any()` accepts an `IEnumerable<T>`.  `Select()` will be evaluated *when it is needed* and since you are using `Any()` it many not even need to enumerate the entire collection which makes it faster than pushing the results to an array (with ToArray()).

Comment: This would only work if there is a space before and after a word? If i had a description that started with "the ", it would not return.

Comment: That's absolutely true.  If it were me, I would have a list of words to ignore (a, the, in, of, etc.) and not use those words as search terms.  Then there is less of a need to deviate from your original solution and you do not run into the problem your pointed out with my solution.