# Sort results based on occurrences

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq

I'm currently building a forum that allows for users to ask questions and to answer them.
To make it easier for users to look up a certain question, I'm trying to build a search engine. 
The code for which:

```
List<QuestionDto> dto = _db.Questions.Where(x => (x.Title.Contains(temp) || x.Message.Contains(temp) || (x.User.FirstName + " " + x.User.LastName).Contains(temp) || x.User.LastName.Contains(temp)) && (categoryId == null || x.Category.CategoryId == categoryId))
            .Select(question => new QuestionDto { QuestionId = question.QuestionId,
                Votes = question.Votes, Title = question.Title,
                Message = question.Message, CategoryName = question.Category.Name,
                EditDate = question.EditDate, DateOfCreation = question.DateOfCreation,
                User = new UserDto { UserId = question.User.Id, FirstName = question.User.FirstName, LastName = question.User.LastName, ImageFile = question.User.ImageFile },
                Tags = question.Tags.Select(x => x.Tag).ToList()
            }).ToList();
```

String temp is used to search through the questions, to see if either the title, message or username matches the query.

What I'm trying to accomplish now is to sort the results on the amount of hits found in a question. So for example if the user searches for the word "PHP" the result would be:

Question 1: PHP was found 10 times
Question 2: PHP was found 5 times
Etc etc..

How would one approach this?

Comment: Asking a programming Q about you Q&A-site, on a programming Q&A-site... Bold move :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you want to find occurrences of the temp word within that list of properties you used to search in db with Contains().

This is a step by step process, that will give you a dictionary with a question id and the number of occurences. You can use this dictionary to order your question list.

Of course this can be optimized.

If you need questions to be ordered, you can use the dictionary and order them. If you need only to display number of occurrences, u will have the dictionary which will provide you data in the following manner: Question #QuestionId, Number Of Occurences of the searched string.

Assuming that word is PHP you will have: , ,  and so on. Records won't be ordered in dictionary.

I added a order step for that dictionary.

Later Edit: If you tried to use Regex in your approach, please be aware that you cannot use Regex in your select statement, but you can use Regex after you bring all the records in memory (after `.ToList()`). Please use the following question as a reference: [Using "Match" in a Linq statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3493501/using-match-in-a-linq-statement)

```
 List<QuestionDto> dtoQList = _db.Questions.Where(x => (x.Title.Contains(temp) || x.Message.Contains(temp) || (x.User.FirstName + " " + x.User.LastName).Contains(temp) || x.User.LastName.Contains(temp)) && (categoryId == null || x.Category.CategoryId == categoryId))
        .Select(question => new QuestionDto
        {
            QuestionId = question.QuestionId,
            Votes = question.Votes,
            Title = question.Title,
            Message = question.Message,
            CategoryName = question.Category.Name,
            EditDate = question.EditDate,
            DateOfCreation = question.DateOfCreation,
            User = new UserDto { UserId = question.User.Id, FirstName = question.User.FirstName, LastName = question.User.LastName, ImageFile = question.User.ImageFile },
            Tags = question.Tags.Select(x => x.Tag).ToList()
        }).ToList();

        var questionDictionaryMatchings = new Dictionary<int, int>();

        foreach(var question in dtoQList)
        {
            var titleSplited = question.Title.Split(new char[] { '.', '?', '!', ' ', ';', ':', ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

            var messageSplited = question.Message.Split(new char[] { '.', '?', '!', ' ', ';', ':', ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

            var firstNameSplited = question.User.FirstName.Split(new char[] { '.', '?', '!', ' ', ';', ':', ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

            var lastNameSplited = question.User.LastName.Split(new char[] { '.', '?', '!', ' ', ';', ':', ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);


            var titleSplitedQuery = from word in titleSplited
                             where word.ToLowerInvariant() == temp.ToLowerInvariant()
                             select word;

            int wordCountTitle = titleSplitedQuery.Count();

            var messageSplitedQuery = from word in messageSplited
                                      where word.ToLowerInvariant() == temp.ToLowerInvariant()
                                    select word;

            int wordCountMessage = messageSplitedQuery.Count();


            var firstNameSplitedQuery = from word in firstNameSplited
                                    where word.ToLowerInvariant() == temp.ToLowerInvariant()
                                    select word;

            int wordCountFirstName = firstNameSplitedQuery.Count();

            var lastNameSplitedQuery = from word in lastNameSplited
                                    where word.ToLowerInvariant() == temp.ToLowerInvariant()
                                    select word;

            int wordCountLastName = lastNameSplitedQuery.Count();

            questionDictionaryMatchings.Add(question.QuestionId, wordCountTitle + wordCountMessage + wordCountFirstName + wordCountLastName);

        }
          //sorted dictionary
          var questionDictionaryMatchingsSorted = from entry in questionDictionaryMatchings orderby entry.Value descending select entry;
```